# How to re-arrange html elements order of display with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to re-arrange the order of item based on a certain value that particular div or element holds for example here is the following snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {

    var spanElemenet = document.getElementsByClassName("rs");
    var stringInp = [];
    var numConv = [];
    var sorted;
    for (var counter = 0; counter < spanElemenet.length; counter++) {
      stringInp[counter] = spanElemenet[counter].innerHTML;
    }
    numConv = stringInp.map(Number);
    for (var i = 1; i < (spanElemenet.length); i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < (spanElemenet.length) - 1; j++) {
        if (numConv[j] > numConv[j + 1]) {
          sorted = numConv[j];
          numConv[j] = numConv[j + 1];
          numConv[j + 1] = sorted;

        }
      }
    }
    //This loop is just to display output of sorted list
   for(var k = 0; k< spanElemenet.length;k++)
   {
     $("#output").append(numConv[k] + "<br>");
   }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">One : <span id="s1" class="rs">400</span></div>
  <div class="item">Two : <span id="s2" class="rs">1200</span></div>
  <div class="item">Three : <span id="s3" class="rs">5000</span></div>
  <div class="item">Four : <span id="s4" class="rs">1096</span></div>
  <div class="item">Five : <span id="s5" class="rs">99 </span></div>
</div>
<button>Re order me</button>
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Until now i am able to get value from HTML and sort them in ascending order the main part is to **now display the whole elements inside container based on this order and also along with its div element**

The O/P i am expecting would be like this :

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">Five : <span id="s5" class="rs">99 </span></div>
  <div class="item">One : <span id="s1" class="rs">400</span></div>
  <div class="item">Four : <span id="s4" class="rs">1096</span></div>
  <div class="item">Two : <span id="s2" class="rs">1200</span></div>
  <div class="item">Three : <span id="s3" class="rs">5000</span></div>
</div>
<button>Re order me</button>
```

Comment: Have you Googled `How to re-arrange html elements order of display with javascript or jQuery`? Several promising-looking results there, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you require you simply need to implement your own `sort()` logic on the `.item` elements, which reads and compares the text from their child `.rs` elements. Something like this:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $('#container .item').sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt($(a).find('.rs').text(), 10) - parseInt($(b).find('.rs').text(), 10);
  }).appendTo('#container');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">One : <span id="s1" class="rs">400</span></div>
  <div class="item">Two : <span id="s2" class="rs">1200</span></div>
  <div class="item">Three : <span id="s3" class="rs">5000</span></div>
  <div class="item">Four : <span id="s4" class="rs">1096</span></div>
  <div class="item">Five : <span id="s5" class="rs">99 </span></div>
</div>
<button>Re order me</button>
```

Comment: can you explain me why you have passed 10 as an argument inside parseInt()

Comment: It's the radix: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: and is there any way to get the order of element back to its initial order with a different button click event

Comment: Yes, you'd need to store the original order of elements (in an array for example) then reset it under that button click. I'd suggest starting a new question about that if you require

Comment: if you can just edit the answer here would be great because it would be like an extension of this question rather actually being a question. i hope you don't mind :)